# $s_n\to s$ and $t_n\to t$. Show that $s_nt_n\to st$

Tags: calculus, analysis

$s_n\to s$ and $t_n\to t$. Show that $s_nt_n\to st$

I took the test and only got half of the score. Please tell me what I did wrong.

**My solution**

Since $s_n \to s$ and $t_n \to t$, we have that $\forall \sqrt \epsilon \gt 0, \ \exists N_1$ such that $\lvert s_n - s \rvert \lt \sqrt \epsilon$ and $\exists N_2$ such that $\lvert t_n - t \rvert \lt \sqrt \epsilon$. Choose $N = \operatorname{max}(N_1, N_2)$. Then, if $n \ge N$

$$\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \ \operatorname{d}((s_n - s)(t_n - t), 0) = \lvert (s_n - s)(t_n - t) \rvert \le \lvert s_n - s \rvert \lvert t_n
- t \rvert \le (\sqrt \epsilon)^{2} = \epsilon$$

Thus $\lim_{n \to \infty}(s_n - s)(t_n - t)=0$ and (using the other theorem of converge) $\lim_{n \to \infty}s_n t_n = st$.

Comment: you need to check that $\lim_n (s_nt_n - st) = 0$. This is different from checking $\lim_n (s_n - s)(t_n-t) = 0$, and you need to show that this second one implies the first

Comment: The way I would grade this depends on what exactly you wrote in place of *using the other theorem of converge*. It is possible to complete the proof from here, but you need to be more specific. As a test problem an underlying assumption may be that you are only supposed to use the definitions. If that was not detailed in the problem description, you can plead your grade. Assuming that you explained the implication Calvin Khor described.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I didn't think that omitted parts are important. Actually I wrote the specific explanation in place of (using the other theorem of converge): $\lim_{n\to \infty}(s_n-s)(t_n-t)=\lim_{n\to \infty}(s_nt_n-st_n-s_nt+st)=\lim_{n\to \infty}(s_nt_n-st_n-s_nt+st)=\lim_{n\to \infty}s_nt_n-\lim_{n\to \infty}s_nt-\lim_{n\to \infty} st_n+st=0$<br/>Thus $\lim_{n\to \infty}s_nt_n=st$. You mean this is not enough, right?

Comment: I think that is good enough. Some ideas where a strict marker may try to remove points; (1) $\forall \sqrt \epsilon$ is not strictly correct use of the notation. Similarly maybe they were expecting "$\exists N_1>0$ such that for all $n>N_1$..." instead of $\exists N_1$... (2) Maybe you are supposed to explicitly mention that $\lim_n s_n t_n$ exists before the computation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clarify why your final statement $lim_n(s_n - s)(t_n - t) = 0$ implies that $s_nt_n$ converges to $st$.

Observe that $s_nt \to st$ and $st_n \to st$. Thus, $s_nt_n = (s_n-s)(t_n-t) + (st_n + s_nt - st)$ is convergent and its limit is $0 + st = st$ (using limit laws).

Comment: You mean this is not enough, unless I show $\lim_{n\to \infty}st_n=st$. Is it right?

Comment: Yes. You need to conclude the argument using limit laws as in my solution.